# selectRowAtIndexPath failing in viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I've got a menu that's a `UITableview` in a `UIPopovercontroller` that when selected scrolls the parent view's UIScollView to a specific frame.

It's working great.

The problem is if you use the pageControl to scroll the frame I need to update the selected row in the table `[_delegate returnPageNumber]` returns the current pageControl.currentPage

No errors, NSLog is reporting the correct page number:

```
scrollIndexPath is <NSIndexPath 0x1a3380> 2 indexes [0, 3]
```

But the correct cell doesn't highlight... why????

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //[tableView reloadData];
    int isPage = [_delegate returnPageNumber];
    NSIndexPath *scrollIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(isPage) inSection:0];
    NSLog(@"scrollIndexPath is %@",scrollIndexPath);
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:scrollIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];      
}
```

I've tried putting `[tableView reloadData]` before and after and having the code in viewDidAppear... nothing works

Comment: Why are you not using -didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now working!

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [[self tableView] reloadData];

    int isPage = [_delegate returnPageNumber];

    NSIndexPath *scrollIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(isPage) inSection:0];
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear scrollIndexPath is %@",scrollIndexPath);

    [[self tableView] selectRowAtIndexPath:scrollIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

The thing that made the difference was disconnecting the view outlet and then reconnecting it to the tableview. Not sure why this made a difference? I tried adding a view controller to the nib but it made no difference, so deleting it and reconnecting the view to the the tableview suddenly produced results. Voodoo.

Answer (score 2):

try calling `[super viewWillAppear]` after everything else, in `viewWillAppear`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{

    NSIndexPath *selection = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    [[self tableView] reloadData];    


    if (selection)
    {
        [[self tableView] selectRowAtIndexPath:selection animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];        
    }

    [super viewWillAppear:animated]; //Trick is calling super last in this case. Then you can  retrieve previously selected row to --> NSIndexPath *selection

}
```